# How to save Windows Server Event Log to CSV using task scheduler

Tags: taskscheduler, event-viewer

I am trying to save Windows Server Event Log to CSV using task scheduler, for a regular interval period. Is there a built in function on the task scheduler or is there a special script to run?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [psloglist](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psloglist.aspx) from SysInternals suite.

```
psloglist /?
```

Will give you all the possible command-line switches.

For instance to export the errors one day behind you could do:

```
psloglist -s -d 1 -f e >> c:\Temp\SysEvtLog.csv
```